# How to Transpose the Entries in the 2nd Column of Grouped Data in Python to Each Be in Their Own Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

Basically I have data that looks like this, with the data grouped by Company and Program and the top 3 Programs by Revenue listed for each Company:

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjSdy.png)

That I would like to look like this, where the Companies are on the rows still, but its top 3 Programs are now in their own column, no need to keep the Revenue values in the visible output:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGWiJ.png)

I've tried a few solutions but it wasn't shaping quite the way I expected and I'm having difficulty finding the exact solution online

I'm new to Python so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heavily abbreviated your data frame images. [In the future please do not upload images of code but instead give the text itself.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) Many corporate networks disable image loading.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'c': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'p': list('WCXANV'), 
     'r': [10, 5, 3, 13, 7, 1]})
```

Create descending ranks within each company:

```
df['t'] = df.sort_values(by=['c', 'r'], ascending=False) \
    .assign(t=1).groupby('c')['t'].cumcount() + 1
```

Stack on company and rank then unstack rank and reset indices.

```
>>> df.set_index(['c', 't'])['p'].unstack().reset_index()
t  c  1  2  3
0  A  W  C  X
1  B  A  N  V
```

I usually think geometrically though so, for me, `stack` and `unstack` operations are very intuitive. Alternatively use `pd.pivot`:

```
>>> df.pivot(index='c', columns='t', values='p')
t  1  2  3
c         
A  W  C  X
B  A  N  V
```